# Write a method which does two logics within one loop

Tags: java, logic

I have a method which iterates over a list. In the for loop it puts something in a Map which is passed as an argument to that method. The very next line will check for some condition and decides to put something in a list or not. The list is again passed as an argument to that method. This is how it looks like

```
public void method(List<ClassA> cas, Map<String, ClassB> map, List<ClassB> list) {
    ...
    for(ClassA ca : cas) {
        ...
        ...
        map.put("key", cb);
        if(someCondition evaluated on ca) {
            list.add(cb);
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a good approach? Someone wrote this code and I don't like this because this method is manipulating the arguments.

I have two solutions.

Solution1: Make two methods. The methods will return map and list. If I use this I will iterate the loop two times.

Solution2: Create some class which holds the list and map. The above method will return an object of the new class created. Then invoker will use getter methods to get the map and list. This way I will have only one method and the loop will iterate for once.

Again I don't like the second solution because a method should perform only one task according to good programming principles.

What you guys say?

Comment: I vote for solution one, unless the method is a possible bottle neck. I think that clean is preferable over quick and dirt. But this method could hide the need for a deeper refactoring.

Comment: @holap Hi, can you please explain this "But this method could hide the need for a more deep refactoring". I did not understand this.

Comment: I don't see why the question code is a bad approach. After all you only iterate `cas` once to fill both `map` and `list`. Wouldn't that better in performance?

Comment: @holap Dont you think iterating the loop 2 times in both the methods wont make any performance problem?

Comment: @ADTC The code in the question does 2 tasks. A method should only perform 1 task. An add method should only add 2 or more values. It should not print something to the console. Printing is taken care by another method because we dont know where do we want to print it. To a console or a UI or a file.

Comment: Actually, I see the problem here is that most of us think that when we pass arguments into a method, they themselves shouldn't be modified in such a way that the caller can see the changes (immutable). But that is the quirk in Java - if you pass a mutable object, it can be modified by the called method, and the mutation can be seen by the caller. It can be advantageous in some situations, like when you need to "return" more than one object, or you're passing a mutable object to a method for the sole purpose of modifying it.

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya Yes it could, but it depends on the size of cas. If it will always be small I would not care.

Comment: @ADTC Another problem I see is the code is trying to modify the list and map which are passed to the method as arguments. This will effect the original map and list

Comment: (I just explained about arguments being modifiable). In order to avoid the problem of having the original map and list being modified, the caller must pass *copies* of the original map and list. Even if the copies are modified, the original will remain unchanged - BUT this will defeat the purpose of the method, which is expressly designed to modify the passed in mutable objects (map and list).

Comment: @holap The size of `cas` will be big.

Comment: If the size of `cas` will be big, then it's better you do the operation in one loop. You can imagine the "1 task" the method should perform is to populate **both** `map` and `list` because this combining of apparently separate tasks is the sacrifice you make for better performance (you don't need to iterate over `cas` twice).

Comment: @ADTC Yeah, after reading your previous comments I am convinced and I will keep the code as is.

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya Therefore solution1 is not applicable from beginning. You will need to use the second one ore leave the code as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say if you can think of a good name for the class that holds both the list and the map then go for option 2. Here's an example.

```
enum Shape {
  Square(true),
  Circle(false),
  Oval(false),
  Triangle(true);
  private final boolean hasCorners;

  Shape(boolean hasCorners) {
    this.hasCorners = hasCorners;
  }

}

class ClassifiedShapes {
  Map<String, Shape> lookup = new HashMap<>();
  List<Shape> withCorners = new ArrayList<>();

  public void classify(String name, Shape shape) {
    lookup.put(name, shape);
    if (shape.hasCorners) {
      withCorners.add(shape);
    }
  }

}

public void test() {
  System.out.println("Hello");
  ClassifiedShapes shapes = new ClassifiedShapes();
  for (Shape shape : Shape.values()) {
    shapes.classify(shape.name(), shape);
  }
}
```